# Appium: ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory

Tags: java, appium

In my **maven** project, i have the below dependencies:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then, i have a very basic code just to open an app:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
    import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

    File f = new File("src");
    File fs = new File(f,"ApiDemos-debug.apk");

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "myAVD");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());

    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> ad = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
```

But, it complains with the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/ApacheHttpClient$Factory
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:50)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:77)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:67)
    at Appium.Appium.App.main(App.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
```

Are my dependencies wrong?
How can i fix it?

Comment: Pls remove selenium dependency. Java-client comes with selenium deps

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to keep in mind: don't mix selenium & appium dependencies. Appium already [has selenium dependency](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/build.gradle#L61) and explicitly setting one you may cause an issue.

The other reasonable question: you are using quite an old client version, the current one is [7.3.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.3.0) Check what Appium server you got installed and if it is 1.15.x+ you probably need to use fresh client as well.